# SQL - date variable isn't being parsed correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I am pulling a list of invoices filtered by a starting and ending date, and further filtered by type of invoice from a SQL table. When I specify a range of 2013-07-01 through 2013-09-30 I am receiving 2 invoices per company when I expect 3. When I use the built in select top 1000 query in SSMS and add my date filters, all the expected invoices appear.

Here is my fancy query that I'm using that utilizing variables that are fed in:

```
DECLARE @ReportStart datetime
DECLARE @ReportStop datetime

SET @ReportStart = '2013-07-01'
SET @ReportStop = '2013-09-30'

SELECT Entity_Company.CompanyName,
Reporting_AgreementTypes.Description,
Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceAmount,
ISNULL(Reporting_ProductCost.ProductCost,0),
(Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceAmount - ISNULL(Reporting_ProductCost.ProductCost,0)),
(Reporting_AgreementTypes.Description + Entity_Company.CompanyName),
Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate
FROM Reporting_Invoices
JOIN Entity_Company ON Entity_Company.ClientID = Reporting_Invoices.ClientID
LEFT JOIN Reporting_ProductCost ON Reporting_ProductCost.InvoiceNumber =Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceNumber
JOIN Reporting_AgreementTypes ON Reporting_AgreementTypes.AgreementTypeID = Reporting_Invoices.AgreementTypeID
WHERE Reporting_Invoices.AgreementTypeID = (SELECT AgreementTypeID FROM Reporting_AgreementTypes WHERE Description = 'Resold Services')
AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate >= @ReportStart AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate <= @ReportStop

ORDER BY CompanyName,InvoiceDate
```

The above only returns 2 invoices per company. When I run a much more basic query through SSMS I get 3 as expected, which looks like:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [InvoiceID]
      ,[AgreementID]
      ,[AgreementTypeID]
      ,[InvoiceDate]
      ,[Comment]
      ,[InvoiceAmount]
      ,[InvoiceNumber]
      ,[TicketID]
      ,Entity_Company.CompanyName
  FROM Reporting_Invoices
  JOIN Entity_Company ON Entity_Company.ClientID = Reporting_Invoices.ClientID
  WHERE Entity_Company.ClientID = '9' AND 
  AgreementTypeID = (SELECT AgreementTypeID FROM Reporting_AgreementTypes WHERE Description = 'Resold Services')

  AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate >= '2013-07-01' AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate <= '2013-09-30'

  ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC
```

I've tried stripping down the 1st query to include only a client ID on the original invoice table, the invoice date, and nothing else. Still only get 2 invoices instead of the expected 3. I've also tried manually entering the dates instead of the @ variables, same result. I confirmed that InvoiceDate is defined as a datetime in the table. I've tried making all JOIN's a FULL JOIN to see if anything is hiding, but no change. Here is how I stripped down the original query to keep all other tables out of the mix and yet I'm still getting only 2 invoices per client ID instead of 3 (I manually entered the ID for the type filter):

```
--DECLARE @ReportStart datetime
--DECLARE @ReportStop datetime

--SET @ReportStart = '2013-07-01'
--SET @ReportStop = '2013-09-30'

SELECT --Entity_Company.CompanyName,
--Reporting_AgreementTypes.Description,
Reporting_Invoices.ClientID,
Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceAmount,
--ISNULL(Reporting_ProductCost.ProductCost,0),
--(Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceAmount - ISNULL(Reporting_ProductCost.ProductCost,0)),
--(Reporting_AgreementTypes.Description + Entity_Company.CompanyName),
Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate
FROM Reporting_Invoices
--JOIN Entity_Company ON Entity_Company.ClientID = Reporting_Invoices.ClientID
--LEFT JOIN Reporting_ProductCost ON Reporting_ProductCost.InvoiceNumber = Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceNumber
--JOIN Reporting_AgreementTypes ON Reporting_AgreementTypes.AgreementTypeID = Reporting_Invoices.AgreementTypeID
WHERE Reporting_Invoices.AgreementTypeID = '22'-- (SELECT AgreementTypeID FROM Reporting_AgreementTypes WHERE Description = 'Resold Services')
AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate >= '2013-07-01' AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate <= '2013-09-30'

ORDER BY ClientID,InvoiceDate
```

This strikes me as really weird as it is pretty much the same query as the SSMS generated one that returns correct results. What am I overlooking?

**UPDATE**

I've further refined my "test query" that is returning only 2 invoices per company to help troubleshoot this. Below is the query and a relevant subset of data for 1 company from the appropriate tables:

```
SELECT Reporting_Invoices.ClientID,
Reporting_AgreementTypes.Description,
Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceAmount,
Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate
FROM Reporting_Invoices
JOIN Reporting_AgreementTypes ON Reporting_AgreementTypes.AgreementTypeID = Reporting_Invoices.AgreementTypeID
WHERE Reporting_Invoices.AgreementTypeID = (SELECT AgreementTypeID FROM Reporting_AgreementTypes WHERE Description = 'Resold Services')
AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate >= '2013-07-01T00:00:00' AND Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate <= '2013-09-30T00:00:00'

ORDER BY Reporting_Invoices.ClientID,InvoiceDate
```

The above only returns 2 invoices. Here is the relevant table data:

```
Relevant data from Reporting_AgreementTypes         
AgreementTypeID Description     
22              Resold Services     

Relevant data from Reporting_Invoices           
InvoiceID   ClientID    AgreementID AgreementTypeID     InvoiceDate
16111     9         757         22                  2013-09-30 00:00:00.000
15790     9         757         22                  2013-08-30 00:00:00.000
15517     9         757         22                  2013-07-31 00:00:00.000

Actual results from my new modified query           
ClientID    Description InvoiceAmount   InvoiceDate
9           Resold Services 3513.79         7/31/13 00:00:00
9        Resold Services    3570.49         8/30/13 00:00:00
```

Comment: Is there something odd occurring with date formats? I've had something similar and somehow it was applying some localisation and giving unexpected results..

Comment: Just in case `yyyy-mm-dd` is being interpreted as `yyyy-dd-mm` (which can happen in scenarios such as `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;`), did you try using a truly unambiguous format (`yyyymmdd`) instead? You need to show some sample data and a row that is included but not supposed to be (or the opposite).

Comment: That is what I was thinking in that it wasn't setting the time to 00:00:00 and therefore dropping off the 9/30 invoice. I tried setting the @ vars to the ISO standard for date and getting the same. Also tried just 20130701 and 20130930 as well. Here is the one I used with time: SET ReportStart = '2013-07-01T00:00:00'
SET ReportStop = '2013-09-30T00:00:00' (can't use @ in the comment)

Comment: try `Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate < '2013-10-01'`

Comment: I will get sample data with scrubbed company names and update the question momentarily.

Comment: @Bill you can use multiple `@variable` `@names` in the comment. You just need to enclose code in backticks: `

Comment: There's something you're not telling us, because for me, [your query works just fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/107eb/1).

Comment: Can you humour me and change the last line of the query to `AND convert(date, Reporting_Invoices.InvoiceDate) between '2013-07-01' AND '2013-09-30'`

Comment: The BETWEEN gives me the same result. The queries I have posted are direct copy pasta from SSMS and I'm also stumped as to why one works but the other doesn't. It's the same stupid table. When all else fails, maybe I'll just reboot this server and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check 1:** Are you sure you're looking at the same database? Check the lower-hand right corner in SSMS.

---

**Check 2:** A date means different things under different `dateformat` or `language` options.  For example, the date `2013-01-02` means the 1st of February in France:

```
set language french
select cast('2010-02-01' as datetime)
--> 2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
set language us_english
select cast('2010-02-01' as datetime)
--> 2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
set dateformat ydm
select cast('2010-02-01' as datetime)
--> 2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

You can show the current date format options with:

```
select  s.date_format
,       s.language 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions s
where   s.session_id = @@spid
```

Place the above query on top of your other two queries and compare the result.

---

**Check 3:** The effects of an open transaction are visible only in its own session.  So check if there are any open transactions.  You can do so with:

```
dbcc opentran
```

---

**Check 4:** Does the column have a different type from what you're comparing it with?  If so, SQL Server will convert the data type with [lower precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) to the one with higher precedence.

Here's an example:

```
create table t1 (dt date);
insert t1 values ('2010-01-01');
select * from t1 where dt = '1 Jan 2010'
```

This will return a row because `date` has a higher priority than `varchar`.  So `'1 Jan 2010'` is converted to a `date`.  If it were the other way around, `'2010-01-01'` would not match match `'1 Jan 2010'`.

Comment: my result is: mdy us_english

Comment: Is that so for both queries?

Comment: Yep, forgot to add that in my last comment.

Comment: Are there any open transactions?  Check with the added query.

Comment: Just ran both versions to check for open transactions and there are none.

Comment: What's the data type of the `InvoiceDate` column?  Is it a `varchar`, a `datetime`, or a `date` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same database?  (Check the lower-hand right corner in SSMS.)

Comment: HOLY CRAP!!! That was it! I have a dev DB that is an older mirror of my current one, and sure enough it was running the query against that even though I (thought) there was no open connection.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check :

- Is the missing invoice on '2013-09-30'?
- Is the InvoiceDate actually a datetime with a time element?

If you are comparing datetimes, then the time is 00:00 unless specified, which would exclude most of that date. If you want to include that then you can use

```
 < '2013-10-01'
```

or

```
 convert(date, InvoiceDate) <= '2013-09-30'
```

Comment: That is what I thought originally so I used '2013-09-30T00:00:00' and getting the same result. I also set the ending date to '2013-10-30' to get the next month and I'm only getting 2 results still. Really weird.

Comment: These are comments, not an answer.

Comment: @Colin'tHart No. They are steps to identify the problem.

Comment: ie comments, not an answer.

Comment: @BillSambrone Are the invoicingdate fields actually dates, or are they strings?

Comment: They are datetime as defined in the table and also in the declaration. Is there another place I should be checking?

Comment: Is reporting_invoices a view, or a table? How is it populated?

Comment: It is a table. I wrote a C# service that truncates this table every night, then takes data from our ticketing system and inserts it into this freshly truncated table.